# Can I create a regular expression in JavaScript which validates specific math formula - letters and brackets, where brackets should not be nested

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate an input field with regular expression in JavaScript, which should validate the following cases:

Valid:

```
A and B and C and D
(A or B) and C
(A or B or C) and D
(A or B or C or D) and E
A and (B or C) and D
A and (B or C) or (C and D)
A or (B and C)
(A and B) or (C and D)
```

Invalid:

```
A and B and C and 
(A or B and C
(A or B or C) and D or
(A or B or C or D and E
A and or (B or C) and D
A and (B or (C and D)))
A (B and C)
(A and B) or C and D)
(A and B or C and D)
```

Basically I need some letter from A-Z(only upper-case) followed by "and" or "or" and unlimited brackets, but the opening brackets amount should match the amount of closing ones. Also after an opening bracket I should have to be able to insert only A-Z upper-case and after a closing bracket "and", "or" or A-Z upper-case should also be valid. Nested brackets shouldn't also be valid.

I've came up with this solution, but it's only validating A-Z upper-case, "and" and "or" words and brackets, so all invalid cases provided are matching my regex.

```
/^[A-Z(]?[A-Z]| |and|or|[(]|[A-Z]|[)]/gm
```

Comment: You can't do that with a regular expression, not in javascript at least.

Comment: ...and even if you could, it would be painful. Recommend that you read about parsers instead. A simple parser-combinator library would do what you want and probably be easier to understand.

Comment: Are single-variable groups, as in `(A)` or `(A) and B`, considered valid?

Answer (score 2):

Without nested brackets, this is easy. One disjunctive clause of the [conjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) is

```
[A-Z]( or [A-Z])*
```

With parenthesis required around clauses using `or`:

```
[A-Z]|\([A-Z]( or [A-Z])*\)
```

The whole formula would then be

```
([A-Z]|\([A-Z]( or [A-Z])*\))( and ([A-Z]|\([A-Z]( or [A-Z])*\)))*
```

Answer (score 1):

A JS regular expression could be:

```
^(?!\([^()]*\)$|.*([()])[^()]*(?=\1)|[^()]*[()](?:[^()]*[()][^()]*[()])*[^()]*$|.*\([A-Z]\))\(?[A-Z](?: (?:and|or) \(?[A-Z]\)?)*$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/WsoQRf/1)

---

- `^` - Start-line anchor;
- `(?!` - Open a negative lookahead with alternations;

  - `\([^()]*\)$` - Avoid a match with an operning paranthesis, 0+ characters other than paranthesis, and a closing paranthesis. Or;
  - `.*([()])[^()]*(?=\1)` - 0+ Character upto a opening/closing paranthesis in a 1st capture group followed by 0+ characters other than paranthesis upto a backreference to 1st group. Or;
  - `[^()]*[()](?:[^()]*[()][^()]*[()])*[^()]*$` - A check for unbalanced paranthesis. The pattern will enfore there is a multiple of two paranthesis if any has been used. Or;
  - `.*\([A-Z]\)` - Test for 0+ characters followed by opening, capital letter and direct closing, to avoid `(A)`-like input;
- `\(?[A-Z]` - Match an optional paranthesis followed by A-Z (to allow a single letter to be a valid match too);
- `(?: (?:and|or) \(?[A-Z]\)?)*` - Open a non-capture group to match a space, a nested non-capture group to match and|or followed by another space, an optional operning paranthesis, another capital letter and an optional closing paranthesis. This grouping is matches 0+ times;
- `$` - End-line anchor.

Answer (score 1):

Really interesting one... Playing a bit with [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), the shortest I came up so far:

```
^(?:(?:(?!^) (?:and|or) )?(?:\b[A-Z]|\B\([A-Z](?: (?:and|or) [A-Z])+\)\B)){2,}$
```

[Here is a demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hAy0a1/1)

The idea was to keep the length of the pattern short by making the *and/or* part outside brackets [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) and force to occur only at allowed positions. Any groups used are set to [non-capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions).

- `(?!^)` the negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) prevents the optional *and/or* part to match at [start](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)
- `\b` the [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) is used to prevent matching e.g. `AB`
- `\B` the *non word boundaries* prevent matching from e.g. `A(A and B)`

Let me know where/if it fails, I have some feeling it's not working properly yet.